# Does cordova-ios support Xcode 11 and iOS 13 SDK?

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

Just got a notice from Apple that:

> Starting April 2020, all new apps and app updates for iPad will need
>   to be built with the iOS 13 SDK and support the all-screen design of
>   the 12.9-inch iPad Pro (3rd generation).

Does cordova-ios support building with Xcode 11 and the iOS 13 SDK?

Any issues with it handling this iPad Pro?

Comment: Did you find out yet?

Comment: @Tom I did not.

Answer (score 0):

This info from them seems to suggest that Cordova 5.x is compatible with Xcode 11

https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/692

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.